# What are recommended Face Recognition Opensource libraries?

Tags: java, c++, open-source, opencv, face-recognition

On any platforms, what is the best face recognition opensource library for videos.

Answer (score 4):

Opencv allow you to do some things like this.

Comment: Definitely OpenCV. There are samples included that let you perform face recognition from images or even your webcam.

Answer (score 1):

Face recognition is a very complex topic, still being researched. While there may be many libraries ( like opencv ) that are capable of this, some maybe ven opensource, most if not all the hard work is still left up to you. There isn't any library that does all the facial recognition for you.